# getting user location error

Tags: android, mobile, gps, userlocation

I am beginner in android development and i am triying to get user location by gps. i give a error in the following code:

```
 // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
             // makeUseOfNewLocation(location);

                LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;


            }
```

in this line

```
 LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
```

i get an error like this : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to LocationProvider"

what is the problem in that line

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough to debug anyone else's code but this code

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

private MyLocationListener mLocationListener;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location currentLocation;




public class MyLocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // This is where I finally get the latest location information

        currentLocation= location;

        int Bearing = (int)currentLocation.getBearing();

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

}

protected void onResume() {

    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    long minTime = 0;
    float minDistance = 0;
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance,mLocationListener);

}

protected void onPause() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
}
```

}

is what I use in one of my apps to get location info

regards
Simon